# extract or unzip in python over FTP winscp?

Tags: python, ftp

I am new to python script. I have been researched thru here and having difficult to find a right answer. I have compressed zipfile in FTP WinSCP.

I am trying to extract or unzip in python from FTP Winscp? It has compressed zip file in FTP. I have Winscp connect to FTP. I am not sure what is the right script for this case. I already have script set up that has been created by someone else. I am aware that I have host, username, and password FTP already created in script. Please advise. Thank you.

For example, I pulled this part of script like this:  but what about zip file?

```
# List of Other files to download
# Syntax: County file name with extension separated by colon, then
# the FTP Folder name

CountyOtherFiles = {
 'pa_parceldata.dat':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
 'pa_parceldata.txt':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
 'pa_legal_ln.dat':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
 'pa_legal_ln.txt':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
}
```

EDITED: I tried this code and it is an error. Please advise.

```
 ZipFile.extractall(path='GISData/Pubshp', members= 'PaFiles.gdb.zip')
NameError: name 'ZipFile' is not defined
```

EDITED 2: I am using ArcGIS included ArcGIS Server, ArcCatolog and ArcPy. I have GIS Database Connection (SDE feature classes). Is there someone that I can message privately to send a full script and might able to assist me?

Would this work below for zip file??

> CountyOtherFiles = {
>        'pa_parceldata.dat':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
>        'pa_parceldata.txt':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
>        'pa_legal_ln.dat':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
>        'pa_legal_ln.txt':r'GISdata/Pa_data/',
>        ***'PaFiles.gbd.zip':r'GISdata/Pa_data/'***
>       }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide more information about your problem? For example, what code are you currently using to try to unzip your file? What error are you receiving? It helps to have a reproducible example so that the community can help you. See here on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you might not have imported it, try importing this and then using it.This will resolve NameError: name 'ZipFile' is not defined

```
    from zipfile import *
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to run it and this is what I got. ZipFile.extractall(path='GISData/Pubshp', members= 'PaFiles.gdb.zip')
TypeError: unbound method extractall() must be called with ZipFile instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: Please can you post your whole code again and let us know properly what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't think I am using the correct script.  But this is what I put below. 
##### Import Modules #####
import os
import string
import sys
import time
import datetime
from ftplib import FTP
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import pypyodbc
import datetime
from zipfile import * and then I put this. ZipFile.extractall(path='GISData/Pubshp', members= 'PaFiles.gdb.zip')

Comment: That path is I put is from FTP WinScp. Am I doing this correct? I do have a full script that I can private message.

Comment: It is compressed zip file inside FTP WinScp. I need to unzip the file from FTP and download it. Is that make sense?

Comment: try http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=686162&seqNum=7 , it may have helpful resource for you